# Send email usin Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

I want to send email using `Matlab` GUI. I coded the send button like this:

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

mail = 'paddydisease@gmail.com';
password = '123445';

setpref ('Internet','Email',mail);
setpref ('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref ('Internet','SMTP_Username',mail);
setpref ('Internet','SMTP_Password',password);

props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class','javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');

a = get(handles.edit1,'String');
b = get (handles.edit1,'String');

sendmail(a,'Test from MATLAB',b);

set(handles.edite1,'String','');
set(handles.edite2,'String','');

msgbox('Disease deatails Successfully Send')
```

But error message appears like this:

```
Error using sendmail (line 67)

Could not determine FROM address.  You can set one like this:

setpref('Internet','E_mail','username@example.com');

Error in gui>pushbutton3_Callback (line 171)


sendmail(a,'Test from MATLAB',b);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)

        feval(varargin{:});


Error in gui (line 42)

    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});


Error in 

@(hObject,eventdata)gui('pushbutton3_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))



Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: Look at the difference in syntax between your `setpref` call and the one given to you by the error message.

Comment: thanks for help, now i get this error. how fix this

Comment: Error using sendmail (line 171)
Authentication failed.

Error in gui>pushbutton3_Callback (line 193)
sendmail(a,'Test from MATLAB',b);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in gui (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)gui('pushbutton3_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))

 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback